# draw line or place imageview between two imageview which is placed horizontally in linearlayout - android

Tags: android

I want to draw the line between two images.

I place the 3 `ImageView` horizontally in `LinearLayout` with centre alignment for all screens by using weight.

My problem is I want to draw the line between two images which should be touch the both images.

I don't know how to draw line or place the line image between two images which is created by using weight in linear layout. Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Place the three ImageView in RelativeLayout and do some aligning or set paddings

Comment: Set your Image views between Views..

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, I tried but I wan that three images should be same weighted and the line should be touched on the two images that is the problem i am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put View between ImageViews.

```
<View
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="2dp"
     android:background="@color/gray" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertical divider:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/divider_color"
    android:id="@+id/vertical_divider"/>
```

Horizontal divider:

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/divider_color"
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_divider"/>
```

Example usage:

```
<LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/img_1"/>

                    <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/divider_color"
                            android:id="@+id/vertical_divider1"/>

                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/img_2"/>

                    <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/divider_color"
                            android:id="@+id/vertical_divider2"/>

                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/img_3"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```